# Variables being concatinated instead of added

Tags: vbscript

To test what I've learned, I'm making a simple calculator program in VBScript.
It gives the user (me) an inputbox to enter the  first number, one for the operator (+,-,* or /) and a third inputbox for the second number.  The three operators  -,* and /work just fine however when I test addition the program concatinates num1 with num2 rather than adding it, and I cant figure out why.
Here is my code:

```
dim num1,num2,answer,operators
num1 = inputbox("please enter your first number","calculator")
operators = inputbox("please enter either +,-,* or /","calculator")
num2 = inputbox("please enter your second number","calculator")
'keep the above lines, above everything else
Select Case operators
        Case "+"
        answer = (num1 + num2)
        Case "-"
        answer = (num1 - num2)
        Case "*"
        answer = (num1 * num2)
        Case "/"
        answer = (num1 / num2)
        case else
msgbox("please enter a valid operator")
End Select
msgbox answer
```

So the output if I do say 6+7 is 67.
I tried putting '= answer' at the end instead of at the start but it throws an 'expected statment' error.

Any ideas why It's doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputbox returns a String, so "1" + "2" = "12". Try:

```
answer = (CInt(num1) + Cint(num2))
```

More type conversion functions are listed [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_vbscript_functions.asp).